# How to use a variable inside square brackets in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to access a web service from Powershell but am hitting a problem when constructing the query.  I need to reference a variable from inside square brackets to set the datatype similar to the below:

```
$uri = https://webserviceURL

$webs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri 

$webs.New_Create_Tic('PSTic','',[$webs.StatusType]'New','PSTic')
```

This won't work as the variable `$webs` within the square brackets is showing red underlining and causing an error.

I tried `[$($webs).StatusType]` and a whole load more but no joy.

I am able to get this working if I hard code the namespace, but due to a bug, this only works once and then errors for a subsequent execution.  e.g. this will work:

```
$uri = https://webserviceURL

$webs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace PSNS

$webs.New_Create_Tic('PSTic','',[PSNS.StatusType]'New','PSTic')
```

So the question is, in order to use a dynamic namespace for the webservice, how do I construct the contents of the square brackets?

Comment: Did you try quoting? `"$($webs.StatusType)"`

Comment: I don't have a proxy available to test with but you could try casting using `-as`, it should be something like `$StatusType = 'New' -as $webs.StatusType ; $webs.New_Create_Tic('PSTic','',$StatusType,'PSTic')`

Comment: To elaborate on @LievenKeersmaekers does this work? `"[$($webs.StatusType)]'New'"`

Comment: Nick, tried that version earlier with no joy.  It treats the variable as a literal and trys to use it as opposed to defining the type for 'New'.  Only way I can get it working is to create enum list at the start of the script but looks kind of messy but maybe that's the way. Thanks.

Comment: James C, casting with -as gives an error stating that right operand of -as must be a type.  I think I might just stick to using the enum list method as this works fine.  Thanks.